# Numpy - normalize RGB pixel array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, array-broadcasting, normalize

I have a numpy array with shape `(34799, 32, 32, 3)`which means `(num examples, width, height, channels)`.

Now I normalize the image data with the following code:

```
def normalize(x):
    return (x - 128) / 128

X_train_norm = normalize(X_train)
```

But the result seems not right, the value of `X_train[0][0][0]` is `[28 25 24]`, but the output of `X_train_norm[0][0][0]` is `[1.21875 1.1953125 1.1875]`.

I use the following test code:

```
test = np.array([[[[28, 25, 24]]]])
print ((test - 128) / 128)
```

output:

```
[[[[-0.78125   -0.8046875 -0.8125   ]]]]
```

Why the `normalize` function gets the wrong result?

Comment: I think this is due to the wraparound of the bytes.

Comment: What is X_train.dtype ?

Comment: @P.Camilleri uint8

Comment: This explains the behaviour you observe, see the detailed answers provided.

Comment: It solved my problem. thanks very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the images are loaded as a numpy array filled with `uint8` bytes with values between `0` and `255`.

If you perform a subtraction on an `uint8` such that the result is *negative*, a wraparound happens. Like `123 - 128 == 251`, and then you divide it by 128. For example:

```
>>> np.array([28,25,24], dtype=np.uint8) - 128
array([156, 153, 152], dtype=uint8)
```

and then, we get the reported:

```
>>> (np.array([28,25,24], dtype=np.uint8) - 128)/128
array([1.21875  , 1.1953125, 1.1875   ])
```

In order to solve it, you can use `.astype(..)`:

```
def normalize(x):
    return (x.astype(float) - 128) / 128
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that you use a function, if you had used the expression with the original array, you would have had the *same* result.

Answer (score 5):

As the code is currently written, if `x` has dtype `uint8` (which it seems to have), the subtraction will take place in uint8, but the division is done in float.

The easiest way to solve this is to force the subtraction to happen in floats by letting 128 be a float

```
def normalize(x):
    return (x - 128.0) / 128
```